# Conversion of pinescript from Version 2 to Version 5

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

```
/////@version=2
study(title="VDUB_BINARY", shorttitle="VDUB_BINARY", overlay=true)
source = close
length = input(56, minval=1, title = "WMA Length")
atrlen = input(100, minval=1, title = "ATR Length")
mult1 = 2
mult2 = 3
ma = wma(source, length)
range =  tr
rangema = wma(range, atrlen)

up1 = ma + rangema * mult1
up2 = ma + rangema * mult2

dn1 = ma - rangema * mult1
dn2 = ma - rangema * mult2

color1 = white
color2 = white

u4 = plot(up1, color = color1)
u8 = plot(up2, color = color2)

d4 = plot(dn1, color = color1)
d8 = plot(dn2, color = color2)

//Linear regression band
src = close
//Input
nlookback = input (defval = 20, minval = 1, title = "Number of Lookback")
scale = input(defval=1,  title="scale of ATR")
nATR = input(defval = 14, title="ATR Parameter")

//Center band
periods=input(9, minval=1, title="MA Period")
pc = input(true, title="MA BAND")

hld = iff(close > sma(high,periods)[1], 1, iff(close<sma(low,periods)[1],-1, 0))
hlv = valuewhen(hld != 0, hld, 1)

hi = pc and hlv == -1 ? sma(high, periods) : na
lo = pc and hlv == 1 ? sma(low,periods) : na
plot(avg(sma(high,periods)+2.5*(sma(high,periods)-sma(low,periods)),sma(low,periods)-2.5*(sma(high,periods)-sma(low,periods))), color=yellow, style=line,linewidth=4)

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Base line_VX1
source2 = close
short = sma(close, 3)
long = sma(close, 13)
plot(long, color=navy, linewidth=4)
//plot(cross(long, short) ? long : na, style = circles, color=blue, linewidth = 9)
OutputSignal = long >= short ? 1 : 0
//bgcolor(OutputSignal>0?red:gray, transp=100)
//=======================================================
//Vdub_Tetris_V2
LRG_Channel_TF_mins_D_W_M = input("30")
Range2 = input(1)

SELL = security(tickerid, LRG_Channel_TF_mins_D_W_M, highest(Range2))
BUY = security(tickerid, LRG_Channel_TF_mins_D_W_M, lowest(Range2))

HI = plot(SELL, color=SELL!=SELL[1]?na:red,linewidth=4 )
LO = plot(BUY, color=BUY!=BUY[1]?na:blue,linewidth=4 )

Hcon = high >= SELL
Lcon = low <= BUY

plotshape(Hcon, style=shape.triangledown, color=maroon, location=location.abovebar)
plotshape(Lcon, style=shape.triangleup, color=green, location=location.belowbar)
range2 = SELL-BUY
//--------------------------------------------------

SML_Channel_TF_mins_D_W_M = input('240')
M_HIGH = security(tickerid, SML_Channel_TF_mins_D_W_M, high)
M_LOW = security(tickerid, SML_Channel_TF_mins_D_W_M, low)
plot(M_HIGH, color=M_HIGH != M_HIGH[1] ?na:fuchsia, style=line, linewidth=2)
plot(M_LOW, color=M_LOW != M_LOW[1] ?na:fuchsia, style=line, linewidth=2)
```

after conversion of the code into version 5 it is not plotting the lines at its accurate places. the lines are starting from that place should end at that place. I think there is some error in conversion of iff formula. please correct the same to do the better result. This the code of indicator , which I am looking to convert to V2 or V5, i am facing to problem to convert it to desired version. Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

You have `security()` calls in your code. The behavior [Default behaviour of security function has changed](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/migration_guides/To_Pine_version_3.html#default-behaviour-of-security-function-has-changed) starting from v3.

If you want to get the same result, you should add `barmerge.lookahead_on` to your call which is not advisable. You can read [this](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Context_switching_the_security_function.html#understanding-lookahead) for more information about `lookahead`.